# How to adjust axis text - dc.js

Tags: css, dc.js

I am a first time user of dc.js and I want to change the font color and size of the text on the axis of my charts. Does anyone know a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.dc-chart .axis text {
  font-size: /* Insert font size */;
  color: /* Insert color here */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the font color it works better like this :

.dc-chart .axis text { fill: white; }